# Python Boto S3Connection issues through proxy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, proxy, boto

Trying the following code to connect to AWS S3 and push a file using a proxy and getting the following error,

Code:

local_proxy = "http://172.18.96.36
local_proxy_port = 8080
aws_connection = S3Connection(aws_access_key_id = AWS_KEY, aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET, is_secure = True, security_token = AWS_TOKEN, proxy = "172.18.96.36", proxy_port = "8080", proxy_user=None, proxy_pass=None)

mybucket = aws_connection.get_bucket(bucket_name, validate = False)

k = boto.s3.key.Key(mybucket)
k.set_contents_from_filename(source_file, encrypt_key=True)

Error: bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

When I change proxy to "http://172.18.96.36", I get the following error,

Errno -2 Name or service not known

Note : Proxy works fine, when I try it thru aws cli. No issues there. Also, the boto script works fine outside the firewall. Want to see what is incorrect in the S3Connection call or anywhere else.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. https://github.com/lcerezo/scriptz/blob/master/SAtools/pushfiles_toS3.py

what you want is someting along thses lines:

`conn = boto.connect_s3(proxy='172.18.96.36',proxy_port='3128',debug=1)`

the above works for me with squid. change the ports. I don't think you want the `http://` in that string.

Comment: Thx lcerezo.  Port 3128 hangs and nothing comes back.  Btw, Port 8080 works ok thru AWS CLI.  Any idea why I am getting error "bytes-like object is required, not 'str'" ?  That will help.

Comment: Also, I am using python 3.5 with regular boto module.  Would that be an issue?  Shd I use python 2.7 ?

Comment: I think the ip should not be prefixed with http:// it may be interpreting that as a str().

alternatively you could set bash env var `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` to the ip:port eg, `export http_proxy=172.18.96.36:8080`

Comment: also, when I sett https_proxy using command line or os.environ['HTTPS_PROXY'] variable, the process hangs

Comment: I suspect it is trying to gethostbyname('http://xxx') which will never work.

for the timeout, are you using debug=1?